# How to get absolute paths in cmake generated project files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jenkins, cmake

I am using `cmake` to generate project files for a C++ project that needs to be compiled under Visual Studio 6 and 2010. The files are generated OK for both projects and I can build the projects without a problems.

However, the 2010 vxproj files contain relative paths to the `cpp` files and when I use Jenkins to build the files the log contains relative paths that Jenkins can not use to find the source files.

I see this:

> ..\..\source\moduleA\file1.cpp(74): warning C4800: 'BOOL' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

While it should have been either `source/moduleA/file.cpp` or `D:\jenkins\jobs\workspace\source\moduleA\file.cpp` for Jenkins to be able to find the file.

Of course, I can make a parser to parse the log file and remove the `..\...\` but I am hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you show piece of CMake code which adds `source\moduleA\file1.cpp` to the build?

Comment: It looks like it actually found the file - it is giving you a warning when compiling it. Can you post the actual error where it says it cannot find the file? Also, if your error is in VS2010: any reason you are not using the solution file instead of the vxproj directly?

Comment: There is no error compiling.
In the source folder I have one CMakeLists.txt that includes the moduleA. In moduleA I use this:
`file(GLOB GUIDLL_SRC
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
    "*.rc")
    
add_library(GuiDllD SHARED ${GUIDLL_SRC})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found a compiler option that can fix this. You can add the `/FC` flag for Visual Studio 2010. Not sure if it works for VC6. To add it use this:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /FC")
```